# jmeter: How to repeat two thread groups in test plan?

Tags: jmeter

I have two thread groups:

- **setUp Thread Group** - executed only once
- **Thread Group** - executed for number of users defined in CSV file.

The first thread group prepares data once, which will be used by all users in the second thread group.

After finish of the second thread group, I want to repeat the whole process again. This seems not possible, since there is no **Forever** check box for the test plan itself? Using jmeter 2.9

Comment: Any feedback on this ? If answer is ok you should accept it so that it helps others

Answer (score 2):

This is not possible using this way.
You would need to find some hack to do the same thing.

It could be something like:
 While controller that tests a stop condition And has 2 If Controller children

- if controller (tests if first thread and does the setup job, when done sets while controller condition to false

- if controller ( tests if other threads and if not wait 10s)

While controller that contains test code